# Apple-like scrollbars using CSS

Tags: css, browser-scrollbars

I have noticed on some Apple sites like: http://help.apple.com/mobileme/index.html#mm5b08c671 they have custom scrollbars using the WebKit scrollbar CSS stuff that recently came out. However I am unable to replicate it at all. Any ideas how to do it? I have a test site here but I get the default scrollbars? Thanks

Test: http://driz.co.uk/scrollbar/

Comment: link is broken, should be changed...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following CSS monster is what Apple is using:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/kTsUc/886/

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FguQn.png?corner.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
::-webkit-resizer {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKKDY.png?resizer.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start {
    display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end {
    display: block;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ2K6.png?horizontal-button.png) 0 2 0 2;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0 2px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xDbU.png?horizontal-button-background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal:corner-present {
    border-right-width: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQRD7.png?horizontal-thumb.png) 0 15 0 15;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0 15px;
    min-width: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal:start {
    margin-left: 6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal:end {
    margin-right: -6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal:decrement {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9yMk.png?horizontal-track.png) 0 15 0 15;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal:increment {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9yMk.png?horizontal-track.png) 0 15 0 15;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0 15px 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal {
    width: 21px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ2K6.png?horizontal-button.png) 0 2 0 2;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0 2px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGOKL.png?horizontal-decrement-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xDbU.png?horizontal-button-background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position: 7px 4px, 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement:active {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT5BM.png?horizontal-button-active.png) 0 2 0 2;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGOKL.png?horizontal-decrement-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDf8L.png?horizontal-button-background-active.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rJr5.png?horizontal-increment-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xDbU.png?horizontal-button-background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    width: 16px;
    border-left-width: 0;
    background-position: 3px 4px, 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment:active {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT5BM.png?horizontal-button-active.png) 0 2 0 2;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rJr5.png?horizontal-increment-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDf8L.png?horizontal-button-background-active.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment:corner-present {
    border-right-width: 0;
    width: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdaTT.png?vertical-button.png) 2 0 2 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 2px 0;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7j9a.png?vertical-button-background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical:corner-present {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPEsZ.png?vertical-thumb.png) 15 0 15 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 15px 0;
    min-height: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start {
    margin-top: 6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end {
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:decrement {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb6ru.png?vertical-track.png) 15 0 15 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 15px 0 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:increment {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb6ru.png?vertical-track.png) 15 0 15 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 15px 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
    height: 21px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdaTT.png?vertical-button.png) 2 0 2 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 2px 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQvwk.png?vertical-decrement-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7j9a.png?vertical-button-background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
    background-position: 4px 7px, 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:active {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW3TL.png?vertical-button-active.png) 2 0 2 0;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQvwk.png?vertical-decrement-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/puDsH.png?vertical-button-background-active.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjkVR.png?vertical-increment-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7j9a.png?vertical-button-background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
    height: 16px;
    border-top-width: 0;
    background-position: 4px 5px, 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:active {
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW3TL.png?vertical-button-active.png) 2 0 2 0;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjkVR.png?vertical-increment-arrow.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/puDsH.png?vertical-button-background-active.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment:corner-present {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    height: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:disabled {
    background: red;
    -webkit-border-image: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Some useful blog posts:

- http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/
- http://web.archive.org/web/20120115134443/http://numerosign.com/notebook/styling-webkit-scrollbars-with-css3/
- http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task

Comment: It only works in webkit browsers. Firefox and others (non webkit) would require javascript to fully create a custom scrollbar.

Comment: Your styles are all messed up, the only thing visible is the bottom button, everything else is white, in a webkit browser.

Comment: @android.nick: Apple changed the path to their images, that's hardly my fault is it?

Comment: Is this scrollbar still available somewhere? I am desperately looking for it

Comment: @Zubzob: I found the images with my sleuthing skills.

Comment: Can you suggest where can I find the CSS for the scrollbar used in latest versions of Apple apps