# How to change the hover color of a scrollbar button?

Tags: css

I need to change the color of a scrollbar button when the mouse moves over it which is at top and bottom (left and right) of scrollbar. How can I change it in WebKit? When I use hover, it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: If this is the *browser* scrollbar, I suggest leaving it alone. Websites that change things like this create a very user-hostile experience.

Answer (score 3):

You may or may not be able to change the hover styles on scrollbar buttons as this is browser-dependent. <del>Namely, no known browser has hover styles for scrollbar buttons.</del>

**EDIT:** thirtydot points out that scrollbar button hover styles are on their way to WebKit's implementation; see his comment for a demo.

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware of the WebKit way, check my answer.

Comment: @thirtydot: I'm aware, but I don't think it supports hover styles that the OP is asking for. Sweet demo you have there though!

Comment: [See here](http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html) for an example of the "hover styles".

Comment: Oh dear. The end of the web as we know it is near. Tiny, impossible-to-use, custom scrollbars that serve absolutely no functional or semantic purpose are coming to a page near you. Everyone should just **pretend they never saw that demo**.

Comment: @Cody Gray: We'll be alright until someone makes a "WebKit scrollbar generator". When that happens, *then* we're doomed :)

Answer (score 1):

You specifically said "how can i change it in webkit", so:

An older answer of mine:  [Apple-like scrollbars using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641169/apple-like-scrollbars-using-css)

> Apple's version: http://help.apple.com/mobileme/index.html#mm5b08c671
>
> [***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/kTsUc/) (tested in Chrome
>   dev, Safari 5)
>
> Some useful blog posts:
>
> - http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/
> - http://numerosign.com/notebook/styling-webkit-scrollbars-with-css3/
> - http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task

Note that it's rather time consuming to:

- Get it right.
- Make it look good.

It does looks very slick on Apple's help site, so it may be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

So, is possible to change color on a scrollbar, but u have to consider that most browser don't like these css..

```
body {scrollbar-3dlight-color:#ffd700; 
scrollbar-arrow-color:#ff0; 
scrollbar-base-color:#ff6347; 
scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#ffa500; 
scrollbar-face-color:#008080; 
scrollbar-highlight-color:#ff69b4; 
scrollbar-shadow-color:#f0f}
```

Otherwise you can use Jquery for personalize you scrollbar.
Look at this link: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html