# Styling overflow-y scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbars

I'm using overflow-y: scroll. It gives me the generic system scroll. I can't find anywhere that says how to style this. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Colored scrollbar do not work in Gecko-based browsers (Firefox, Netscape Navigator, Mozilla): It is an Internet Explorer's only property. It is not a standard property or a proprietary property. According to W3C, these properties are illegal: they are neither defined in any CSS specification nor are they marked as proprietary (by prefixing them with "-vendor-")

You need to make your own scroll bars. This can be done using jQuery Slider http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll.

Also checkout this link http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Comment: also exists some ie style directives that only work in quirks mode

Comment: `to style it in Mozilla` - you should change that to "recent WebKit browsers".

Comment: Edited. It wasn't meant for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a jQuery plugin called [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) (*[demos](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#examples)*).

A relevant answer I gave about the WebKit scrollbars:

- [Apple-like scrollbars using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641169/apple-like-scrollbars-using-css/4641257#4641257)