# Styling an inner scrollbar like the Twitter conversation interface?

Tags: html, css, twitter, scrollbar

[image: Side panel scrollbar]

The scroll bar can be seen in the side-panel when you click on a tweet and the conversation linked to the tweet is long enough.

**How is the scroll bar created and styled?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They're using `::-webkit-scrollbar` and the associated pseudo-elements, which only work in WebKit browsers (which is fine, because this is just aesthetics).

Take a look at this for more information: [Apple-like scrollbars using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641169/apple-like-scrollbars-using-css/4641257#4641257)

I've taken the CSS that Twitter is using, see: http://jsbin.com/ubasew

```
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar{width:9px;height:9px;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment{display:block;height:0;background-color:transparent;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{background-color:#FAFAFA;-webkit-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical{height:50px;background-color:#999;-webkit-border-radius:8px;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{width:50px;background-color:#999;-webkit-border-radius:8px;}
```

The `#doc` is as Twitter had it, and it's there so that only scrollbars inside `#doc` are customised.

Comment: I bow my head in the radiance of your glorious anwering-skills :)

Comment: Note that this removes the up and down arrows, and ignores the user's scrollbar width settings.  It might be pretty, but it's bad for usability.  It's acceptable for a small iframe or scrollable div, but I wouldn't use it on a whole page.  If you do, at least make the scrollbar look like a scrollbar.  If the gutter color matches the page background, the user may get to the end of the visible area and not even realize there's a scrollbar because the button is way up above.

Comment: is that webkit only ?

Comment: @Webveloper .. up and down arrows are so old school

Comment: This does not work for me, tested on latest Firefox and Chrome, for some reason it does not render the code :(

Answer (score 9):

I believe they are using a jQuery plugin or one created by themselves, either way it's something similar to jScrollPane

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: This is how you'd do it if you needed something that worked in every browser, but it's not what Twitter is using.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll figure out what direction I want to go :)