# Getting the height of a 'Facebook Comments' widget/social plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins, iframe, comments, height

Using Facebook Javascript SDK+XFBML, I'm implementing the fb 'comments widget', as explained [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).

then, using the fbml line:

```
<fb:comments href="someurl.com" num_posts="2" width="400"></fb:comments>
```

creates an iframe with the comments widget.

The height of the iframe is of-course according to the length of the comments; 
 
I need to make changes to my page according to the height of the comments widget. 
I can tap into when the widget has finished loading, by using

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render')
```

(I found it more accurate than using 'ready' or 'load'),
but I cannot get the height of the comments iframe due to cross-domain restrictions.

Does anybody know of some sort of a solution for this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: 
Workaround number 1: (from http://startdevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/03/issue-with-facebook-comments-box-height.html):

add a style to your page:

```
.fb_ltr { height: 400px !important; overflow-y: scroll !important; }
```

'fb_ltr' is the class used by the iframe. This will make sure it's always 400px high, and add scroll-bar to scroll content. 
Of-course, the scroll-bar is ugly, so, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same idea as yours, modified the style, but it will use min-heigh
Please try this,

```
.fb_ltr { min-height:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for you solution, Yuval A. 
Second, I found a clean and simple style for scroll bar here:
[CSS scrollbar style cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser)

In short is this code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {  width: 12px;  /* for vertical scrollbars */  height: 12px; /* for horizontal scrollbars */ } ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); } ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```