# change the css(height) of fb plugin's elements

Tags: css

[image]

hi guys can i change the height of black box(black border in given image).
I read that it is control by fb.
I tried changing its height(320px) from firebug and it does in browser but i can't change in real css code.I even tried using dom method to access the div(class="_4s7c") in my case but failed.Is it really,we cant do anything about that.Please suggest me.Thanks

```
<style>
._4s7c{height:320px !important}
</style>
```

here is what i did in my view page

```
    <div id="fb-root" style="background: #fff;"><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>`<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/EverestWomenTreksdotcom/" width="200"  show_faces="true" border_color="#FFFFFF" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>
    </div>
```

I have changed the iframe height but i need to change the height of the divs that comes insdie the frame.

Comment: Are you adding this(plugin) in an iframe ?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Most likely yes.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690928/getting-the-height-of-a-facebook-comments-widget-social-plugin

This one tackles a similar kind of a problem .

Comment: I think the creation of the like box there is the possibility to define the width in Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#facebookID iframe {
    height:300px !important;
}
```

or

```
#facebookID iframe[style] {
    height:300px !important;
}
```

change the "#facebookID" with your real id from the html code.

Comment: sorry,in my case the frame is exact as i want.so i don't want to change the iframe height or width

Comment: I think its no possible, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe