# How to create color custom scrollbar in pure css?

Tags: html, css

Hi i am trying to create a custom scrollbar in css but I am not able to make it?

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: this is not possible in css you can used jquery.

Comment: Can be done only for Chrome. Here it is how http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: See http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ and http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar both use javascript

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible to do this cross-browser with plain CSS.**

As [@tea-totaler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991944/how-to-create-color-custom-scrollbar-in-pure-css#comment12769747_9991944) has mentioned, it is however possible in [Google Chrome](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/).

It is however possible to do this using javascript/jQuery.

Here is a helpful article containing links to 10 different jQuery Custom Scrollbars:

http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/