# Extjs4 how to change the scrollbar width

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid panel with some data, when ever grid rows exceeds i.e, if the data is more n grid height is small scroll bar ll come . I want to change the style of that scroll bar. I tried following css :

```
     .x-box-scroller
     .x-scroller-vertical
```

But no changes in scroll bar width n style.
 pls someone let me know the correct way to change the Extjs4 scroll bar width and color

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are asking here.  Is there an issue where there are two scroll widths showing up when the inner content reaches a certain height?

Answer (score 1):

The Scrollbar is rendered by the browser and not by ExtJS. The Framework just makes some space for it. Asking your Question as you did can only be answered with no

> Scrollbar CSS styles are an oddity invented by Microsoft developers.
>   They are not part of the W3C standard for CSS and therefore most
>   browsers just ignore them.

this might interest you [stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser)

Comment: oh! then is there any other method to custumize or create our own scrollBars using extjs4

Comment: @hsnGunda Scrollbars created by the browser. They cannot be changed using JavaScript or CSS in any way that would be cross browser conform. So you should and for most browsers cannot do it. Long answer short: No you can't do this.

Comment: Actually, if the asker happens to be using Extjs 4.0.x, they used custom rendered scrollers created and managed by the Extjs library.  They went back to native scrollers in 4.1 because of the plethora of problems created using rendered scrollers.

Comment: @Reimius thanks for that info on that. I thought I had read about that, too. But as their rollback show, there are still to many problems