# Kendo UI Grid : How to change the style of the scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo UI grid with simple scroll bar, how do i change his style ?

Answer (score 3):

Kendo UI Grid relies on the built-in browser scrollbar. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser) question which shows how to style the scrollbar in IE, WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome) and Opera.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery custom content scroller (http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) on the grid content and disable the vertical scrollbar in css.

example:

```
$(".k-grid-content").css("overflow-y", "hidden").mCustomScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the 'Lopo's answer, i suggest you the same solution, but with another plugin for that. Gromo's Jquery.scrollbar is the better one. I have used the both (Jquery.scrollbar and mCustomScrollbar), and the differences are many.

[Gromo's Jquery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar)

[**Scrollbar plugins differences**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sjb7nGrTtflPNtPRkL6fryUEaT4Ls0CrGrpMiAl3YQw/edit#gid=0)