# Cross browser (or close to) CSS scrollbar styling?

Tags: css, scrollbar

There's a lot of material out there on how to style scrollbars in webkit, but next to nothing in any other browser, even though IE was reportedly the first browser to implement it.

What I'm looking for is the equivalent of:

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar {
    ...
}

&::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    ...
}

&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    ...
}
```

in as many browsers as possible.

My philosophy is that if you have crap browser it's your own fault and I'm not willing to switch to a javascript solution over my scrollbar styling. But I'd like to put in a little effort.

Comment: haha thats my philosophy too. if you are using a crappy browser, switch it. lol

Comment: a little outdated post. i dont't know if it still valid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser

Comment: also i am not agains using jquery/javascript if the solution is better so i don't why not use something like this http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/