# How to change the scrollbar color of the browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css, mozilla

I want to change the color of the scroll bar of browser window, I used the following code but its working only in `IE8` and not in other like `Chrome` and `Mozilla`..

```
html {scrollbar-face-color:#D6D7D6 ;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-highlight-color:#EFEFEF;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;

scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-arrow-color:  #000000;}
```

Comment: IE doesn't support `scrollbar-*` properties.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a `jQuery` plugin? Such as [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) or [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/).

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser) question states:

> Scrollbar CSS styles are an oddity invented by Microsoft developers.
>   They are not part of the W3C standard for CSS and therefore most
>   browsers just ignore them.

I'd recommend those `jQuery` plugins, as they are compatible with all browsers.

If you would rather not to use a plugin, it seems that as of 2013, 70% of browsers support some scrollbar styling. Such as this example code for `webkit` browsers: (ie Chrome)

```
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar{width:9px;height:9px;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment{display:block;height:0;background-color:transparent;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{background-color:#FAFAFA;-webkit-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical{height:50px;background-color:#999;-webkit-border-radius:8px;}
#doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{width:50px;background-color:#999;-webkit-border-radius:8px;}
```

Each browser needs a different syntax, I would still suggest using a plugin.