# Editing the scrollbar (CSS / JQuery)

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar

How am I able to adjust the design of the browsers scrollbar? For example, giving it a black color, adjusting it's width, etc.

I'd like to achieve this without using webkit (since I want this effect aswell for IE users, IE7+).

Comment: Are you talking about the actual browser scrollbar or the scrollbar of overflow elements within the page?

Comment: there are many, many plugins for this, why don't you try Googeling it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the scrollbar color of the browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898447/how-to-change-the-scrollbar-color-of-the-browser-window)

Comment: @RhapX yes, i'm talking of the browsers actual scrollbar

Comment: @JacobGray Because all the plugins I found, are codes with 4000+ lines. Which is terrible to have for a smaller website.

Comment: @Bilal075 either use one of those, or make your own :/ the problem with it is it has to create completely new scrollbars with js, then add all the scrolling functionality.

Comment: @JacobGray Damn, so there is no possibility to just adjust the design of the browsers scrollbar? :(

Comment: Nope :( you have to create one to style it

Comment: It isn't actually that hard to create one, i started on it once

Comment: @Bilal075 here is what I started with, feel free to continue working on it if you are any good with js https://github.com/Jacob-Gray/cotyScroll/blob/dev/main.js

Comment: @JacobGray I'll look into one of these plugins I found, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use "Tinyscrollbar" Plugin for That which is  nice and elegant way to enable the scrolling of content on mobile and desktop devices.

I hope it must help you. you can check the link.

> http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/

Good luck