# How to put a style for scrollbar in ul

Tags: html, css

I have certain images which are placed in div's in the ul tag. I get scroll bar for more than 3 images. Any chance that i can apply styles to the scroll bar .

Comment: No you cannot style the scrollbar.

Comment: You can do it in Webkit browsers though. But then, refer to this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser

Answer (score 2):

You can style scrollbar's of webkit browsers

**The css: Applicable for Chrome and safari**

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #b46868;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
      background-color: #7c2929;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: black;
}
```

**Styling internet explorer which is a bit different :**

```
body {
    scrollbar-face-color: #b46868;
}
```

Mark that these will not work for non-webkit browsers. ex firefox
so, for non webkit browsers you need to use a jquery plugin.

For more help refer this site
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-styling-scrollbars-to-match-your-ui-design/

Comment: i want in firefox too..how can i do it

Comment: If you want in firefox too then you need to use jquery and a plugin for that. The name of the plugin and the required info is in the link which i have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: but it lags on iPad ios9