# how to change the colour of the scrollbar using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the colour of the browser's scrollbar of my webpage according to the theme.Is there any way to change the colour of the scrollbar.If yes then how ? plz help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS scrollbar style cross browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser).

Answer (score 0):

If you use **CSS** to make it `colorful` then it may not work in all `browsers`

So you can use [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) by simply using

```
$(function(){
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

**How to use of jscrollpane**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
<style>
    .scroll-pane{width: 100%;height: 200px;overflow: auto;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="scroll-pane" >
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices
            eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci
            mi, in pharetra ligula. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Mauris convallis venenatis massa, quis
            consectetur felis ornare quis. Sed aliquet nunc ac ante molestie ultricies. Nam pulvinar ultricies
            bibendum. Vivamus diam leo, faucibus et vehicula eu, molestie sit amet dui. Proin nec orci et elit
            semper ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
            mus. Sed quis urna mi, ac dignissim mauris. Quisque mollis ornare mauris, sed laoreet diam malesuada
            quis. Proin vel elementum ante. Donec hendrerit arcu ac odio tincidunt posuere. Vestibulum nec risus
            eu lacus semper viverra.
        </p><p>
            Vestibulum dictum consectetur magna eu egestas. Praesent molestie dapibus erat, sit amet sodales
            lectus congue ut. Nam adipiscing, tortor ac blandit egestas, lorem ligula posuere ipsum, nec
            faucibus nisl enim eu purus. Quisque bibendum diam quis nunc eleifend at molestie libero tincidunt.
            Quisque tincidunt sapien a sapien pellentesque consequat. Mauris adipiscing venenatis augue ut
            tempor. Donec auctor mattis quam quis aliquam. Nullam ultrices erat in dolor pharetra bibendum.
            Suspendisse eget odio ut libero imperdiet rhoncus. Curabitur aliquet, ipsum sit amet aliquet varius,
            est urna ullamcorper magna, sed eleifend libero nunc non erat. Vivamus semper turpis ac turpis
            volutpat non cursus velit aliquam. Fusce id tortor id sapien porta egestas. Nulla venenatis luctus
            libero et suscipit. Sed sed purus risus. Donec auctor, leo nec eleifend vehicula, lacus felis
            sollicitudin est, vitae lacinia lectus urna nec libero. Aliquam pellentesque, arcu condimentum
            pharetra vestibulum, lectus felis malesuada felis, vel fringilla dolor dui tempus nisi. In hac
            habitasse platea dictumst. Ut imperdiet mauris vitae eros varius eget accumsan lectus adipiscing.
        </p><p>
            Quisque et massa leo, sit amet adipiscing nisi. Mauris vel condimentum dolor. Duis quis ullamcorper
            eros. Proin metus dui, facilisis id bibendum sed, aliquet non ipsum. Aenean pulvinar risus eu nisi
            dictum eleifend. Maecenas mattis dolor eget lectus pretium eget molestie libero auctor. Praesent sit
            amet tellus sed nibh convallis semper. Curabitur nisl odio, feugiat non dapibus sed, tincidunt ut
            est. Nullam erat velit, suscipit aliquet commodo sit amet, mollis in mauris. Curabitur pharetra
            dictum interdum. In posuere pretium ultricies. Curabitur volutpat eros vehicula quam ultrices
            varius. Proin volutpat enim a massa tempor ornare. Sed ullamcorper fermentum nisl, ac hendrerit sem
            feugiat ac. Donec porttitor ullamcorper quam. Morbi pretium adipiscing quam, quis bibendum diam
            congue eget. Sed at lectus at est malesuada iaculis. Sed fermentum quam dui. Donec eget ipsum dolor,
            id mollis nisi. Donec fermentum vehicula porta.
        </p><p>
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero
            sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
            Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed,
            commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros
            ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis.
            Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna
            eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
            luctus, metus
        </p><p>
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit
            amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
        </p>
    </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZY9T/)

Comment: I have given the class named scroll-pane to a div to check it.but where to put the styling of scrollbar?

Comment: how to use jScrollPane()?

Comment: @S_PRATAP Check my updated answer, also `download and upload` the `script` and `style` when you use it on your `server`

Comment: I have pasted this code as it is.only one change I have made that is height 900px. but it looks normal like this:http://www.sendspace.com/file/4xfd6p

Answer (score 0):

you can change the scroll bar in the browser's which support webkit like chrome,safari,opera, etc by adding following css and edit them on basis of your theme:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
overflow-x:hidden
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
    overflow-x:hidden

}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    overflow-x:hidden

}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
}
```

you can also use external script like  jscrollpane but it make your page heavy.

Comment: it did not work.I have pasted this code in my css file but there was no effect.

Comment: the above code only work in browser which support webkit. so test it on browser like chrome.