# Scrollbar style for pdf element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I have a div that contains an object "linked" to a .pdf document.

Is there a way to change the scrollbar style either with css or javascript/jquery?

```
<div id="container">
  <object data="document.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
  </object>
</div>
```

Another question: I tried to pass data object in this way:

```
<object data="document.pdf#view=Fit" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
</object>
```

But pdf don't fit to the div.. where I'm wrong?

## Edit

Starting from more simply example, I try to hide scrollbar following [this document](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf), using this code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27GE8/2/).

Doesn't work.

Is the problem the browser? I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Styling scrollbars is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser

Comment: I've already seen this answer.. but works only with div scroll, not for pdf scroll...

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question, use the below URL,

http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Hope this url will help you.