# IE vertical Scrollbar Width with CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Is there a way with CSS and HTML or any javascript lib like jquery or angular i can reduce the width of the scrollbar. I am using IE 10

[image]

Comment: Try to Use custom Scrollbar (content scroller ) http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS scrollbar style cross browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use plugin or own css jquery for this to do so.
the easiest way is to download the plugin ?

[click here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-scroll-bar/)
i hope it solved your problem .

Comment: this will not help...there is no way to reduce the width

Comment: Now check it again .i Change my link ?

Comment: i could see the page before also..but this is not helping me..did you try it which property you think i need to set to reduce the width. the image i have taken from msdn also explain the same property.

Comment: it depend on the plugin you use.
i use [this](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

Comment: are you able to reduce the width of the vertical scrollbar

Comment: i don't need to re-size ,[check this](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) nice scroll it's good plugins .