# Mouse peripheral causes the styling of the scrollbar to change

Tags: javascript, css

Mouse peripheral causes the styling of the scrollbar to change. How do I prevent this from happening or change the background color of the scrollbar box so that it matches the rest of my site?

This is the desired effect when I have scrollable content:

Without Mouse Plugged In

[image]

This is the undesired effect when I have scrollable content with a mouse plugged in:

With Mouse Plugged In

[image]

Here is a link to code that models the scrollable portion in question:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

I'm experiencing this issue my Macbook Pro (I haven't done any testing on a Windows device.) I'm looking for a solution that works in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Link to code that models the scrollable portion in question: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Comment: Generally you don't style system elements like scroll bars. They are different across systems and OS's. What about Ipads which don't have any scroll bar at all? I would be more concerned about my content and page styling than scroll bar aesthetics. so long as your styling is dynamic and can re-size should a scroll bar appear next to it instead of on top you'll be fine. However this answer provides other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser Its not standard so they all allow you to do it differently.

Comment: @ste2425 Generally speaking, I don't want to style the scrollbar but instead choose which default style is being applied.

Comment: The default style is the style the browser or operating system gives. Its not a user selectable setting. i suspect your system is going from desktop to mobile mode when the mouse is removed.

Comment: Update: This effect/issue does not present itself with an Apple Magic Mouse; only when I use a third party mouse. Since I can't ask our users to use Apple products only this revelation does not help.