# How do I change the height of a vertical scrollbar on a page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="container scrollnew">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus tortor eget orci fringilla non semper magna aliquet. Aliquam convallis elit sem. Proin fringilla fermentum pretium. Phasellus id nisl eu eros convallis eleifend. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In at felis massa. Maecenas vitae quam non elit porta pellentesque ac in erat. Nullam a ante felis, ullamcorper suscipit felis. Maecenas sit amet nisl mattis ipsum ullamcorper aliquam vitae sed sapien. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
```

`::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical`

How do I change the height of the vertical scroll bar?

Comment: .scrollnew::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
 height:30px !important;
}

Comment: i have try this one but not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7725687/4711865

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to style the height of the scrollbar as it is determined by the amount of content you have on your page.

The following code might help you understand how to use these values:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 12px;  /* for vertical scrollbars */
  height: 12px; /* for horizontal scrollbars */
}
```

The width and height properties on the scrollbar element indicate the width of the vertical scrollbar and the height of the horizontal scrollbar.