# Render scrollbar different on Windows vs Mac

Tags: css, scroll

The rendering of the scrollbar is really different on windows vs the rendering on Mac.

How can I fix it to make the same design as the standard one on Mac ?
Do I have to create a whole custom css for the scrollbar ?
Thanks !
Nathan

[Windows rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LB39.png)

[Mac rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn9e7.png)

Comment: You're in for a bad time on this one. You need to implement a library since you cannot by default style the scrollbar. Look into this, for example: https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS scrollbar style cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser)