# Is there a solution to style scrollbars globally?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've found [the article](https://itnext.io/dark-and-light-scrollbar-at-runtime-with-vue-and-vuetify-3809076e547d) about scrollbar styling with Vue and Vuetify which says: "This solution comes with one drawback. We can’t apply the style globally for all components."

I wonder if there is a solution to style all scrollbars globally?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser

Comment: I use this plugin for a cross browser solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.scrollbar also allows me to only target desktop scrollbars if I want to

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can define a global.css/global.scss file wherein you can specify the following styling

```
/* Scroll bar stylings */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }

  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: var(--lightestgrey); 
  }
  
  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  /* Handle on hover */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
  }
```

and import it in your main.js file using

```
import '../styles/global.css' // specify the path depending on your file structure
```

Answer (score 3):

Styling scrollbars for the Safari/Chrome world is exposed behind the -webkit vendor prefix.

You can assign this in your header file that include in all files within  &

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

The -webkit-scrollbar family of properties consists of seven different pseudo-elements that, together, comprise a full scrollbar UI element:

1. `::-webkit-scrollbar` addresses the background of the bar itself. It is usually covered by the other elements
2. `::-webkit-scrollbar-button` addresses the directional buttons on the scrollbar
3. `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` addresses the empty space “below” the progress bar
4. `::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece` is the top-most layer of the the progress bar not covered by the draggable scrolling element (thumb)
5. `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` addresses the draggable scrolling element that resizes depending on the size of the scrollable element
6. `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` addresses the (usually) bottom corner of the scrollable element, where two scrollbars might meet
7. `::-webkit-resizer` addresses the draggable resizing handle that appears above the scrollbar-corner at the bottom corner of some elements

Supported Browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Accepted anwser might be good but it didn't worked well for me so I came up with another sollution:

You don't have to import anything in *main.js*.

By default *index.html* is in *public* folder so all you you need to do is to create file *scrollbarStyle.css* in this folder and add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= BASE_URL %>scrollbarStyle.css">
```

to your `<head>...</head>` in *index.html* and thats it! ;D

Enjoy your custom scrollbars across your app!