# How can I make a div scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout in which I will like to align contents in a horizontal direction but let each row scroll-able in horizontal direction only. Here is my [JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/ps26y3c5/).

```
.x-scroller{
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    overflow-y:hidden; 
    height:100px; 
    width: 300px
}
```

The .x-scroller DIV will be dynamically generated in a loop with her contents, each of the x-scroller DIV will equally have some contents which I will like to be able to scroll in horizontal direction only as can be seen in the picture below:

[image: The .x-scroller DIV will dynamically generated in a loop with her contents each of the x-scroller DIV will equally have some contents which I will like to be able to scroll in horizontal direction only]

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want. You want the 2 paragraphs of text to be next to each other?

Comment: It can be as many divs as possible, each will occupy a row (display: block) of its own but I want the contents to be horizontally scroll-able

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/ojvhuumx/) what you're looking for?

```css
.outer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.outer div {
    width: 24.5%;
    background-color: #eee;
    float: none;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0 0.25%;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: WooooooW!This is exactly what I want. Please @John_C will it be possible for me to style the Scroll bar? I am try to inspect it on the browser but I can't get the DOM that is showing scroller

Comment: Styling the scrollbar is a separate issue. See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713599/styling-an-inner-scrollbar-like-the-twitter-conversation-interface/7713784#7713784

Comment: Yes I know, I will follow up with post. Thanks once again

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this my manipulating the css [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property

```
.x-scroller {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ps26y3c5/1/)

Comment: also, if you add "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" it gives the scroller a native bounce effect in apple devices.

Comment: The containing div has a definite height. This currently forces the contains to occupy only but one line. It doesn't address my issue

Comment: I can have up to 10 divs (with class x-scroller), each of these divs will occupy a row. But I want there contents to be horizontally scroll-able

Comment: I have Updated my post with an image to help explain what i intend to achieve

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by adding the display property to inline-block. [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tzmsj43z/)

```
.x-scroller{
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This splits the text into two long horizontal lines, but looks less than desirable given the current text.

```
.x-scroller{
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    height:100px; 
    width: 300px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```