# How are scrollbars in new Google Docs UI styled (esp. the arrow buttons)?

Tags: css, scrollbar, styling, google-docs

The new Google Docs UI features cool gray scrollbars.

[image: Screenshot of the Google Docs UI]

These appear to be regular scrollbars styled with selectors like `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`. Which is nice and accessible.

However, I can't get arrow buttons to appear (circled on the screenshot). Inspector shows no corresponding DOM elements or any special CSS. So the question is, **how these custom scrollbars are made, including the arrow buttons?**

Please check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hMXL/2/).

Edit:

So it seems that just not all css rules appear in the Inspector.

In particular, you'd need `::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement` and `::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment`, and their `horizontal` equivalents.

Please see [**new fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hMXL/199/) (updated 27 Apr. 2012).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641169/apple-like-scrollbars-using-css, and I think you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the css tags for the handles don't show up in Chrome's dev tools. You have to examine the source of the sample to see what is really going on.

http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

Comment: Looks like that website went down. I found their cached page: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.webkit.org%2Fblog%2F363%2Fstyling-scrollbars%2F

Answer (score 16):

Hope this can help you:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background: #ebebeb;
    overflow: visible;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    display: none;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
    height:0;
    width: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment             {
    display: block;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement {
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -moz-background-clip: border;
    -webkit-background-clip: border;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical, ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical,::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal,::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical,::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal,::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical,::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal,::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical,::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    min-height: 28px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical, ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Added -moz- and -webkit-. I additionally fixed a border issue. Works great now.

Comment: Why add -moz? It doesn't seem like adding any other vendor prefixes would matter in this case since the style being declared is specific to webkit.

Comment: A wonderful, plug-and-play, elegant and customizable solution. Thousand thumbs up!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
::-webkit-scrollbar{height:16px;overflow:visible;width:16px}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button{height:0;width:0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background-clip:padding-box;border:solid transparent;border-width:0 0 0 7px}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal{border-width:7px 0 0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05);box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05);box-shadow:inset 1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),inset -1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:hover{box-shadow:inset -1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),inset 1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical:hover{box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);background-clip:padding-box;border:solid transparent;border-width:0 0 0 7px;min-height:28px;padding:100px 0 0;box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{border-width:7px 0 0;padding:0 0 0 100px;box-shadow:inset -1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35)}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background:transparent}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{background-clip:padding-box;background-color:#f5f5f5;border:solid #fff;border-width:0 0 0 3px;box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07)}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal{border-width:3px 0 0;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07)}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-clip:padding-box;border-width:1px 1px 1px 5px}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{border-width:5px 1px 1px}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background-clip:padding-box;background-color:#f5f5f5;border:solid #fff;border-width:3px 0 0 3px;box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14)}.whiteBox,.greyBox{padding:16px 0;margin-bottom:16px}.greyBox{background:#f1f1f1}.kd-ruledBox{width:100%}.kd-greyRuled{border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5}.kd-whiteRuled{border-top:1px solid #ebebeb}#openid-icon{background:no-repeat url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==") -36px -70px;width:16px;height:16px}#lj-icon{background:no-repeat url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==") -45px -165px;width:16px;height:16px}#wp-icon{background:no-repeat url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==") -16px -101px;width:16px;height:16px}#typekey-icon{background:no-repeat url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==") 0 -101px;width:16px;height:16px}#aol-icon{background:no-repeat url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==") -45px -133px;width:16px;height:16px}.icon_delete{background:no-repeat url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==") -32px -101px;width:13px;height:13px}.errormsg{text-align:left;background:url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAPAMQfAP+tHgAAAC4tLR4eHkRDQ//0kIB/f7q3rf/LU/rvsF9eXvr49f/mdv/WZ0I+MtrU0v/Xid++U8+hN7+/j//9w5OQjt/di7+wW/+7OIB/S6+WQhAPDc/PqMC+vSAbC+7n5SH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAQAA8AAAWB4CeORCA8Y5oegRIYauw4lBOgsVgFU8EFhJxo4LBkLK5DbjfJBC6JzSBHpDgvjB0stTsULs9GQrDBDQmUbyCCQLAUo12nwGA42hiIqzOk1TUeEhiDCxsOH3J0DBobggAAEAYBFQMCCwl1EA1tCHkLAwMBAwakpaakGyYBq6ytrQIhADs=") no-repeat left top;padding-left:24px;margin-top:5px;color:#c00}#openIdUrlPreviewFade{background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==) 0 0 repeat-y;position:absolute;right:.5em;width:32px;height:100%;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/img/openid-preview-fade.png',sizingMethod='scale',height='100px')";_background-image:none;z-index:1000}#comments-block dt{margin-top:10px;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:.25em;white-space:nowrap;cursor:pointer}#comments-block dt.collapsed{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc}#comments-block dd{margin:0 0 .75em;line-height:140%;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc}#comments-block dd.collapsed{display:none}.profile-image-container{float:right;margin:.4em 0 .2em .8em;position:relative;z-index:2}img.profile{padding:.2em;border:1px solid #bbb}.status-msg-outer{position:relative;margin:33px auto 0 auto;z-index:100;text-align:center}.status-msg{visibility:hidden;padding:6px 16px;background:#f9edbe;border:1px solid #f0c36d;-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;opacity:0;-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-transform:scale(.2);-moz-transform:scale(.2);-o-transform:scale(.2);transform:scale(.2);-webkit-transition:opacity 1s,-webkit-transform 0 linear 1s,left 0 linear 1s;-moz-transition:opacity .13s;-o-transition:opacity .13s;transition:opacity .13s}.status-msg.status-msg-yellow-on-white{visibility:visible;opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale(1);-moz-transform:scale(1);-o-transform:scal(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transition:all .13s,left 0 linear 0;-moz-transition:all .218s;-o-transition:all .218s}.status-msg span{margin:0;line-height:29px;font-size:11px}.status-msg a{color:#333;text-decoration:underline}.kd-butterbar a:hover{color:#202020}.kd-butterbar.mini{margin-bottom:-5px}.kd-modaldialog.visible{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale(1);-moz-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}.kd-modaldialog{-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-ms-box-shadow:0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);background:#fff;left:50%;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:30px 42px;position:fixed;right:auto;width:512px;height:auto;overflow:hidden;z-index:100;top:72px;margin-left:-256px;opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale(1.05);-moz-transform:scale(1.05);transform:scale(1.05);-webkit-transition:all .218s;-moz-transition:all .218s;transition:all .218s}.kd-modaldialog.medium{padding:28px 32px;width:384px}.kd-modaldialog.small{padding:16px 20px;width:256px}.kd-modaldialog h1{margin-bottom:1em}.kd-errormessage{color:#dd4b39;padding:9px 0}textarea.kd-formerror{border:1px solid #dd4b39}</style>
</style>
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. Seems to work, and looks good. http://jsfiddle.net/GYmbc/ Edit: Except that it's missing the arrows that the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

A quick, easy, cross browser solution would be to use a jQuery plugin like [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrow_positions.html)