# How to redesign the page Scroller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have a website and would like to design a page scroller myself rather than the default scroller. I was really eager to know how to do this because I am not able to find any tags so as to add or apply a css to this page element. Any idea how this will work. Please let me know the relevant sources and the source code that is compatible with the modern browsers and the old browsers as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742143

I think you will find your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Google's scroller is heavily criticised in usability tests.

Comment: I till now no where found that they are criticized.... it so please provide relevant information about how and why it should be avoided??

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend it at all.

In creating your own scroller you are interfering with the natural UI of the browser and may well cause accessibility issues.

Also, the scroller is redundant on touch-screen devices (phones, iPad, etc).

Comment: Even Google uses it. Just check the latest google page as in the news page. You could find a customized scroller. Anyhow if you know it, would be a great for me!! :)