# Customize scrollbars using css in MVC Razor

Tags: html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm theming scrollbars in my project to particular div using following example: [Example](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CustomizedScroll/).

Well my issue is, using simple html markup file works perfectly on Chrome but after integrating that files in MVC Razor it doesn't give the result I wanted.

Had look on some post like: [Apple-like scrollbars using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641169/apple-like-scrollbars-using-css) & gone through some other post like: [CSS scrollbar style cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser) but no success.

Does the browser just ignore the webkit theme? If it is ignoring then why it's working with a simple html?

The whole code I'm using currently can be downloaded from [here](https://css-tricks.com/styling-scrollable-areas/).

How can it be solved?

Comment: plunker :-  http://plnkr.co/edit/dI0LsTGJvUAJR5lvOBM4?p=preview

Comment: Do you really need it? The user expects scrollbars to look like they do on the rest of his system. If it aint broke - don't fix it.

Comment: Giving effect to scrollbars gives a good effect on website , the stock scrollbars look ugly , which makes my user interface poor . Any help though ?